# How to assign local variable with a remote command result in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm writing a script to restore Master-Slave replication on a set of servers. Lost in bash syntax trying to assign a local variable with a result of a remotely ran command substitution with local values:

```
function doRemote() {
    ssh s1.domain.com   <<ENDSSH
        mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="DROP DATABASE db; CREATE DATABASE db;"
        mysql -u root -pXXX --database=db < $WORKDIR$FILENAME
        sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql/db-bin.*
        mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="FLUSH LOGS;"
        CURRENT_LOG=`mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $1}'`
        CURRENT_POS=`mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $2}'`
        # ...
ENDSSH
}
```

The two lines assigning CURRENT_* variables are the problem: the `mysql -u...` command gets executed locally, instead of remote session.

Please advice how to run that remotely, assigning the local variable with a result of a remote mysql command.

Comment: made it work with one-liners:
`CURRENT_LOG=$(ssh s1.somain.com "mysql -u root -pXXX --execute=\"SHOW MASTER STATUS\" -AN | awk '{print \$1}'")`

Answer (score 6):

Try escaping `ENDSSH` as shown below, so that variable evaluation occurs on the remote host:

```
ssh s1.domain.com <<\ENDSSH
    # ...
ENDSSH
```

Comment: This way it works on remote, but also the `$CURRENT_LOG` variable becomes a remote one. How do I copy two remote vars back to the originating machine?

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping your calls for cmd-substitution

```
CURRENT_LOG=`mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $1}'`
```

now is

```
CURRENT_LOG=\`mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $1}'\`
```

or join the 90's ;-) and use the `$( ... )` form of cmd substitution (escaped also)

```
CURRENT_LOG=\$(mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $1}' )
```

You might have to use more than one `'\'` char to get proper escaping.

IHTH

Comment: Tryed with 1..3 backslashes – false.

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, (and its been 2-3 years since I did any of this), but I know I've surprised myself that I've had to use as many as 5 '\' chars. This will not solve the problem of having the var values appear in you local environment. I think you'll have to capture and parse output from the remote on the local side. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

So, you have two completely distinct problems:

- you are running embedded commands locally, before invoking `ssh`, that you intended to be running remotely, as part of the input passed over `ssh`.
- you are assigning variables on the remote host that you intended to assign on the local host.

Other answers have already covered #1 (namely: better escaping), so I'll cover number #2.

#2 is tricky, but one approach is to modify the `ssh` command to *print* the assignment statements that need to run locally. You can then wrap it in an `eval` command that runs those assignment statements.

All told, you end up with something like this:

```
function doRemote() {
    eval "$(ssh s1.domain.com <<'    ENDSSH'
        mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="DROP DATABASE db; CREATE DATABASE db;" >&2
        mysql -u root -pXXX --database=db < $WORKDIR$FILENAME >&2
        sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql/db-bin.* >&2
        mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="FLUSH LOGS;" >&2
        printf 'CURRENT_LOG=%q\n' `mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $1}'`
        printf 'CURRENT_POS=%q\n' `mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $2}'`
        # ...
    ENDSSH)"
}
```

(Note that I added `>&2` to all the previous commands, so their output goes to standard-error instead of standard-output. This is because standard-output gets captured and `eval`'d locally, which obviously you wouldn't want.)

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to store the contents of the entire here document in a variable and then pass this variable as an argument to the `ssh` command.

Adding some `echo` statements makes it possible to access the `${CURRENT_LOG}` and `${CURRENT_POS}` variables on the local machine. Just make sure `$ssh_output` below only contains the output of the `echo` statements (but also see: [Run a parallel command while waiting for ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113822)).

Do not redirect stdin from a here document if `ssh` is going to execute `sudo` prompting for a password.

```
# untested
function doRemote() {

cmds="$(cat <<'ENDSSH'
mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="DROP DATABASE db; CREATE DATABASE db;"
mysql -u root -pXXX --database=db < $WORKDIR$FILENAME
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql/db-bin.*
mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="FLUSH LOGS;"
CURRENT_LOG=`mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $1}'`
echo "export CURRENT_LOG='${CURRENT_LOG}';"
CURRENT_POS=`mysql -u root -pXXX --execute="SHOW MASTER STATUS" -AN | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "export CURRENT_POS='${CURRENT_POS}';"
# ...
ENDSSH
)"

# use ssh -t for sudo command
ssh_output="$(ssh -t s1.domain.com "$cmds")"
eval "$ssh_output"
return 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doRemote() {

ssh localhost <<ENDSSH
        ls
        cat /etc/issue
        VAR1=\$(/home/thumper/bash/test2.sh)
        echo \$VAR1 >> /home/thumper/bash/test.txt 
ENDSSH
}

doRemote
```

Comment: trying to accomplish that without temporary files.