# Capture output of remote command in variable inside of a shell script

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a script I want to run on remote via ssh. It checks if there is a process running and should try to kill it, if it exists. Now, my code looks like this:

```
ssh my_prod_env << ENDSSH
...
pid=$(pgrep -f "node my_app.js")
echo $pid
# kill process with $pid
...
exit
ENDSSH
```

The problem lies here: I cannot capture output of pgrep command in variable. I tried with $(), backticks, pipe then read and maybe other approaches, but all without success.

I would like to do it all in one ssh session.

Now I am thinking the output of command goes to the output stream I cannot access in my script. I might be wrong, though.
Either way, help will be appreciated.

Comment: ssh my_prod_env | pgrep -f "node my_app.js"  ?

Comment: I guess it works but can I avoid connecting once again only for this command? I have to stay on remote server to do something else after this command finishes and would like to do it all in one ssh session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what fixes the thing - "escaping" the ENDSSH tag.

```
ssh my_prod_env << /ENDSSH
...
# capture output of remote commands in remote variables
...
ENDSSH
```

Problem was that my vars were local and I was trying to capture output of remote commands in them.

This question/answer helped me realize what is going on: [How to assign local variable with a remote command result in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143535/how-to-assign-local-variable-with-a-remote-command-result-in-bash-script)

So, my question could be marked as duplicate or something similar, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after you provided in comments more info what you want, I believe this is the correct answer to your question:

```
ssh my_prod_env -t 'pgrep -f "node my_app.js"'
```

This will call the command and leave you logged on the server